# Inferring Types for rowData and cellData in Columns Array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a type for the following data structure:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    dataKey: 'field1',
    label: 'Field 1',
    render: ({ rowData, cellData }) => {
      return null;
    },
  },
  {
    label: 'Actions',
    render: ({ rowData }) => {
      return null;
    },
  },
]
```

I wan't to be able to type the columns with a generic type and infer the types of rowData and cellData in each object of the list. If the dataKey is not present in the object, the cellData should be undefined.

I was able to get it almost working, when I specify the dataKey, both rowData and cellData shows with the correct types. But without it, the rowData becomes any, but if I put any value that is not part of the correct type typescript will complain but it will not infer the correct type.

```js
type ColumnDef<T, U> = {
  label: string;
  render: (args: { rowData: T; cellData: U }) => null;
};

type ColumnWithoutKey<T> = ColumnDef<T, undefined>;

type ColumnWithKey<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends infer TK
    ? { dataKey: K } & ColumnDef<T, TK>
    : never;
}[keyof T];

type HasDataKey = {
  dataKey: string;
};

type Column<T, U = any> = U extends HasDataKey
  ? ColumnWithKey<T>
  : ColumnWithoutKey<T>;

type Columns<T> = Array<Column<T>>;

type Data = {
  field1: string;
  field2: number; // only work if I have two or more fields
};

const columns: Columns<Data> = [
  {
    dataKey: 'field1', // can autocomplete the dataKey values
    label: 'Field 1',
    // rowData type is Data and cellData is string, both are correct
    render: ({ rowData, cellData }) => {
      return null;
    },
  },
  {
    label: 'Actions',
    // both rowData and cellData types are inferred as any
    render: ({ rowData, cellData }) => {
      return null;
    },
  },
  {
    label: 'Actions',
    // will complain that field3 doesn't exist in the render type, but if I change it to field2, the type continues any
    render: ({ rowData: { field3 } }) => {
      return null;
    },
  },
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2ARCAzAPAFQBooBVAPigF4oBvAWACgooEBDAIwgQC4oBnYACcAlmgDmAbkbNBENABMIg3gApWgsX140oguAHcMrYK174JUAMZcERk7xJQAvgEoqFNEgQIpDJ78ZQSFhEVDQAdWFgAAs4JGAAaQgQAgpqeGR0LDwiKCQFHFEIeTIAhiDoDLDImKSU-DTaaSgAbQSoUSgAa2S4bCh8AF0zNsGoCAAPYDl5Pg60bCUBhObmAH5aKHljVjredqcoADIQzMwcAmJ8BLJVqF40CAA3JV8nFp6QPoHBsoqoAASrD4dl2ySoTSYWx2e34QlEkkY-kYgXAlVC6EupAhrDQIEajkm0wUcyBIJhyWaGyq6Bq0TqqWavBpESisXiDIafzRpzCfFSEIAgoJBKwUizUqUUeUeaCIfQodhhFx5ABGXgCETiXzMJUqgBMD1QnEEFgA9GaoHA0AgQFB9HBBF0Ov0AJJQaKsF5QYAOq2CKAoR3QPUIWZIsqWa0CKwYtBaXnofmgxotZoK5jMbYmWEAclDatzxAtVlxUFY8TgUZQYAQEGmPui0GzYLtT1YyAgfDubE4PCguYAYsqw1BVUW7iW9IYdj6ecI5nLcfIrDY5Qu4VqxMR2HAYuXZLGRRBLMA7rICsooCodNPQcRrN45a53JDM5nZMAkII0FBPN4dUzJxCGaYD0x7DguF4XNBVPYRownKFmBLXd9zvWdl1XJ9ZwqOZ1GgURFmPFdgXLPFzxmJRVFvAx7yw2xZxfSgKAzd9dHrb9f3-Hw7jAqE+OYVjmF7KCB1g4B4PjRD3xLfRhG8WMazYToYmMKACwAZi2OAuzQXNgHGCYFwMlSm3Yy850gHd4hdKB3UsT1xAIgzgDgdSR3kfViBiaB-ijNAJM8LsyJACjL2o3RaJ2bR3JVLTDiYli7hkDifz-LweKQ5wQP4nLfiAA)

Comment: In your title: "_Typescript not inferring the correct type_. What type? "Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title. For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587). The title can be improved by giving a bit more information / context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an explicit (optional) `dataKey` property in your `ColumnWithoutKey` type as well, with type [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#the-never-type), so that `Columns` type becomes a proper [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) (of columns with `dataKey` + column with undefined `dataKey`):

```
type ColumnWithoutKey<T> = {
  dataKey?: never; // Explicit undefined discriminant property
} & ColumnDef<T, undefined>;
```

And now it works as expected:

```
const columns: Columns<Data> = [
  {
    dataKey: 'field1', // can autocomplete the dataKey values
    label: 'Field 1',
    // rowData type is Data and cellData is string, both are correct
    render: ({
      rowData,
      //^? Data
      cellData
      //^? string
    }) => {
      return null;
    },
  },
  {
    label: 'Actions',
    render: ({ // Okay
      rowData,
      //^? Data
      cellData
      //^? undefined
    }) => {
      return null;
    },
  },
  {
    label: 'Actions 2',
    // will complain that field3 doesn't exist in the render type
    render: ({ rowData: { field3 } }) => { // Error: Property 'field3' does not exist on type 'Data'.
      return null;
    },
  },
  {
    label: 'Actions 3',
    render: ({ rowData: { field2 } }) => { // Okay
      //                    ^? number
      return null;
    },
  },
];
```

Works as well with a single Property data type:

```
const columns2: Columns<{
  field0: boolean;
}> = [
    {
      dataKey: 'field0',
      label: 'Field Zero',
      render: ({ // Okay
        rowData,
        //^? { field0: boolean; }
        cellData
        //^? boolean
      }) => null
    },
    {
      label: 'Row actions',
      render: ({ rowData: { field3 } }) => null // Error: Property 'field3' does not exist on type '{ field0: boolean; }'.
    },
    {
      label: 'Row actions 2',
      render: ({ rowData }) => null // Okay
      //         ^? { field0: boolean; }
    }
  ];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2ARCAzAPAFQBooBVAPigF4oBvAWACgooEBDAIwgQC4oBnYACcAlmgDmAbkbNBENABMIg3gApWgsX140oguAHcMrYK174JUAMZcERk7xJQAvgEoqFNEgQIpDJ78ZQSFhEVDQAdWFgAAs4JGAAaQgQAgpqeiYoeWNWJJAAfl40CAA3JQsAegqoAFEADzAEYUsoqCQFHFEIeSzhPksRFFFWNGAoMD1IQVBGJygAMhDkdCw8IjaO7C75MgCGIOh4ZYio6LzUqlppKABtBKhRKABrZLhsKHwAXTM7z6gIOrAOTyPgPNDYJQfBLXfK0LI5PK8e5zRZHMKrAjEfAJMjXIqlcqzG4vEBvD6fPYHKAACVYfDsuWSlwyzGyJkR-CEokks0p4EOoXQmNIlxGIDSIoBQIUoNp9IRyRhSzCkRi53wuMyvDR6FVsXi6t2jEC-OV6D4F2oAEFBIJWCkdWhUkaGCbggzmdctlx5ABGXgCETiXzMb0IeQAJiKqE4gkq1TgaAQICg+jggieD3eAEkoNFWGUoMA01B01AUOnoGGQbzjQxLImBFZBWgtGbW7gGRKbtcWcx4ezkrwAOTV33D4hVKwjKCseJwBsoRoQIFF6LQNmMlMlVjICB8a7MNicHhQYcAMWEPqg48Ih6gU70hhyRdNfSgHpGPWs3g978D3LEOwcAxLOsjNraECWMA96yB0yhQCofb9roBgMnemQoVUAB6+T3swP62Dk+EPhUuH3q47hXJh-ayMASCCGgUCeN4Ib9k4GHMBxvb3seXAjla0HCI2E6wcCSiqDoU4APJPPaJFPuhJE4XhNEETYDLKWRqkoZRlAUMhtErgxTEsT4FGcc4lmGXxp7DoJwDCa2UARqJNFTvowjeM2S5sI8MTGFA1YAMxZHA+5oMOYwAn0Yz+euujiYIr6QGJ8GSahz72HCIXOM4bj6XCU41La6a8AACpMSigGeIXDmF+7MSB-x1LFpZMVSw4MsOAB0CnGYxzFeOZNHcZkY3MDZHD8WeDlOaCwVuShcGKAhSGZQy2hBVe4YRnlekGaRUCyfJalHShF2XSh5FnXRJlDaxFnXGNFJ1g2rZjA2xx8FG7YWn21YAAy8MBiAQCMvhON296GayCogCOQNLRdtkjpe14AFpKHAyPLUlGUyXJIAkTIaE5JZl0qSTVgacRZ3MFTZ0HQ9CBPTRsMsNNdkAEoGLOQkiRTRnpYhOiKTkW25XMzNmUdJV6AhlVwFMNWjjt8iLQ1oJoM1MVNomKXQMOOhAyDcBgxDzi9WzKEc6jZ68-o-OOY2Lm48Lq0ZeLJj5VRsuE6dlPVFdUA3bp1wUkAA)

---

BTW, you can simplify your `ColumnWithKey` and `Column` types, there is no need for conditional type in these cases:

```
type ColumnWithKey<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { // No need for conditional type and inference
    dataKey: K
  } & ColumnDef<T, T[K]>
}[keyof T];

type Column<T> = // No need for conditional type, direct union
  | ColumnWithKey<T>
  | ColumnWithoutKey<T>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-X6HRGJiHYOAYhRWQoQdCAFVvWQOmUKAVF7PtdAML1CFvZgqgAPXydCv28L1cKwnCD2cNxKAoRC+1kYAkEENBgS8HxbycNDMhYntbyPLheCHW0FTFPgbxImDFDghC7ygAB5J4nVwh9UMIipsNw6x8JyRTlJI1x3CuEiZCXWj6M8bwIz7di2NY5hKK4k9eP4xsoGjISkL+fRhG8KEFzYR4YmMMEL3kABmLI4D3NAhzGCA6j6MYfOiaARKUZ8IGguRRNUHR5JyH5R2CuZtPI2gJJqB0IV4AAFSYlFAYdcqHEK92BYCoCimLS3o5Ehy9IcADo5IMuiGJM5jLOcUbrI4bjhz40UHMC5yqLSpQMuQx97CK0do2cUidJ0P5pNkvSJKQk7TqQzTTuowyhqYrTRvM1l3QYBt2zGBsW1jNtrV7UcAAZeCAxAIBGXwnC7G5b0o3EB2SHi-oWpCbJ488AygAAtJQ4ARxbYJW-aZJAXCZBQnJRtOoiibw2x1KOjClOI06Co8RiRsh3CkeHAAlAwUXs9tsf03H4Mykn1p0XLtqZm7itKuDKrgKYapHAL5oavgmsi6Km2hZLh3FgL-qgQGEGBtALCcXrWZIqGWEm2zuf0XnZvbRyBd0JaxJFtbvSl4zEXxw7yeqM6oAuszrlZIA)

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm having other issue, when I have an optional field in the Data type the rowData becomes any again, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Was able to fix the issue by changing [K in keyof T]: to [K in keyof Required<T>]: :)